# FAB gets in front of expanding Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, bottom-sheet, android-architecture-navigation

I have a `FloatingActionButton` on the top left of my layout and a `BottomSheetBehavior` on the bottom of the `CoordinatorLayout`.

The `BottomSheetBehavior is actually inside a`NavigationFragment` destination.

If my `FloatingActionButton` has any `android:elevation` different then `0`, then when the `BottomSheetBehavior` expands to take the fullscreen space, the `FloatingActionButton` stays on top of the `BottomSheetBehavior`, whereas it was supposed to be behind it. The Bottom Sheet was supposed to slide on top of the FAB, hiding it behind it.

Here's a sample of the `FloatingActionButton` on top of the `BottomSheetBehavior`:

[image: FAB on top of Bottom Sheet]

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/menu_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:elevation="1dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/map"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|left"
        app:rippleColor="@color/lightGrey"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/ride_nav_graph" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**How can I fix this, without losing the `FloatingActionButton` elevation effect?**